# IE has better support on Unicode chars than Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, unicode, utf-8

I've tested it here, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8test.htm

No talking about the miscellaneous ones.

Is it Windows 7 fonts? Is it Chrome rendering? Is it some configuration I should tweak?
Any help is welcome.

**EDIT:** I've just checked that UTF-8 was selected in Chrome codification, and it was.
Strangly I can see more symbols in IE 11 (!)

**EDIT 2:** Comparision -> http://bit.ly/font-rendering-chrome-ie

(I guess I should have posted this on the superuser forum, but I can't move it myself.)

Comment: It is a typically a font issue. The webpage is likely asking for a font that you do not have installed to support the Unicode characters being displayed.

Comment: So Chrome doesn't have a font which contains a large Unicode symbols to look up there instead? How does IE show me a lot more? Very smoothly btw.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers use a fallback font if some Unicode characters aren't available in a font. It seems that the implementation of that fallback mechanism differs in IE and Chrome.

One possible solution is to use a different `font-family` for Unicode characters. For Windows systems, I typically use Lucida Sans Unicode with a CSS rule like this:

```css
.unicode {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: ok, that file called Custom.css? how do you know that a class named "unicode" is always applied?

Comment: This only works for your own websites, not globally.

Comment: oh, I was talking about unicode glyphs in general, while surfing the web.
I've tried by changing the default Sans-serif "Arial" to "Lucida Sans Unicode" in Chrome settings, however it seems the same...